# How to set custom loglevel in winston using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums, winston

i have declared `LogLevel` in `enum`, winston is throwing an error. so what should be the type of `levels` ?

***logger.ts***

```
enum LogLevel {
  trace,
  debug,
  info,
  warn,
  error
}

const logConfig = {
  format: _format.json(),
  levels: LogLevel,
  transports: [
    new _transports.Console() 
  ]

const logger =  createLogger(logConfig);
```

***error***

```
Argument of type '{ format: Format; levels: typeof LogLevel; level: string; transports: _transports.ConsoleTransportInstance[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LoggerOptions'.
  Types of property 'levels' are incompatible.
    Type 'typeof LogLevel' is not assignable to type 'AbstractConfigSetLevels'.
      Index signatures are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SOLUTION***

Instead of passing enum directly to levels define a const in key-value pair as shown in `_logLevel`.

```
enum LogLevel {
  trace,
  debug,
  info,
  warn,
  error
}

const _logLevel = {
  error: LogLevel.Error,
  warn: LogLevel.Warn,
  info: LogLevel.Info,
  debug: LogLevel.Debug,
  trace: LogLevel.Trace
};

const logConfig = {
  format: _format.json(),
  levels: _logLevel,
  transports: [
    new _transports.Console() 
  ]

const logger =  createLogger(logConfig);
```